# dash/plotly going hysterical at interval = 500

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

So, i am building a project that reads a sensor data and plot the acquired data using plotly. Using `interval = 1000` works fine but `interval = 500` causes the graph to go hysterical.

This is the video of my graph going crazy: https://youtu.be/0X424syBdDM

Here is the code:

```
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
import random
import plotly.graph_objs as go

class L(list):
    def append(self, item):
        list.append(self, item)
        if len(self) > 5: del self[0]
X = L()
X.append(1)
Y = L()
Y.append(1)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='graph-update',
            interval=800, # in milliseconds
            n_intervals=1
        ),
    ]
)

@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')])

def update_graph_scatter(input_data):
    X.append(X[-1]+1)
    Y.append(Y[-1]+Y[-1]*random.uniform(-0.1,0.1))
    data = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(
            x=list(X),
            y=list(Y),
            name='Scatter',
            line =  dict(shape =  'spline' )
            )
    return {'data': [data],'layout' : go.Layout(xaxis=dict(range=[min(X),max(X)]),
                                                yaxis=dict(range=[min(Y),max(Y)]),)}
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same behaviour and was able to stop it by setting `animate=False`.